# Excel formula without using symbols

Tags: excel

`=(E5*90%)+(G5*10%)` Anyone can help me please. I want this formula to be written in excel as in SUM or PRODUCT or whatever should be used but no symbols as in `+` or `*` . Thank you.

Comment: Look at the excel formulas for SUM and the excel formula for PRODUCT

Answer (score 0):

```
 =sum(product(E5,0.90),product(G5,0.10))
```

That would technically be symbol free since % is a symbol....you would not normally write it this way.  The way you had it the first time is the common way to place it in excel.

Comment: I tried it, it is only calculating the first part without adding the second one.
Is there anyway I can make it work using the SUMPRODUCT but no array just specific values as the 90 and 10%?

Comment: @N.Hab thats funny, why would you want to make it so difficult?

Comment: @KSSheon It is an assignment.

Comment: i see, but SUMPRODUCT only accepts array inputs. so its not possible to give static input formula wise

Comment: I know, but the thing i don't understand is in this one "=sum(product(E5,0.90),product(G5,0.10))" the "product(G5,0.10)" is not being calculated though I am sure this is the correct formula. @KSSheon

Comment: break it into its parts.  Take three adjacent cells.  In the first put the first product equation.  in the second put the second product equation and in the third put the equation = sum(first cell, second cell)

Comment: In order to use the function SUMPRODUCT, it would be important to see how your data is layed out on your page.  SUMPRODUCT is very possible but the layout is also very important.